# How can I duplicate this in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
/* Modify the footer row to match what we want */
var nCells = nRow.getElementsByTagName('th');
nCells[1].innerHTML = iPageCPSV;
nCells[2].innerHTML = iPageCGV;
nCells[3].innerHTML = iPagePPSV;
nCells[4].innerHTML = iPagePGV;
```

It works just fine as it is.  However I have added another `<tr>` into the section now.  And I am having trouble figureing out how to populate the `<th>` in the second `<tr>`

```
<tfoot>
    <tr style="background-color: #DDDDDD;">
        <th align="right" colspan="6">
            Page Total:
        </th>
        <th align="left"></th>
        <th align="left"></th>
        <th align="left"></th>
        <th align="left"></th>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #DDDDDD;">
        <th align="right" colspan="6">
            Downline Total:
        </th>
        <th align="left"></th>
        <th align="left"></th>
        <th align="left"></th>
        <th align="left"></th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Before I added the second `<tr>` with more `<th>` everything worked.  It still works, I just don't know how to populate the data into the second row.  Can anyone help me modify the existing JavaScript or tell me how to duplicate it into jQuery?

Comment: `th` is a cell for table heading. Strange to have two headings in table. BTW, your current code has nothing to do with JQuery.

Comment: @mellamokb that was my first guess as well, but they came up as being undefined.

Comment: @vision But the question does as it was asked to duplicate this in jquery. ;)

Comment: @VisioN: Not only that, but the `th` is in a `tfoot`??

Comment: <th> is a selector.  It is commonly used in the <thead> section.  However you can use <th> anywhere.  You can use it in the <thead> <tfoot> or <tbody> and it works just like <td>.

Comment: @James, `<th>` is an element, not a selector, but you're perfectly right otherwise.

Comment: Element, my bad.  Brain is fried!  Thanks @FrédéricHamidi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without jQuery...

```
var foot = nRow.getElementsByTagName('tfoot')[0];
foot.rows[0].cells[1].innerHTML = iPageCPSV;
foot.rows[0].cells[2].innerHTML = iPageCGV;
foot.rows[0].cells[3].innerHTML = iPagePPSV;
foot.rows[0].cells[4].innerHTML = iPagePGV;

foot.rows[1].cells[1].innerHTML = iPageCPSV;
foot.rows[1].cells[2].innerHTML = iPageCGV;
foot.rows[1].cells[3].innerHTML = iPagePPSV;
foot.rows[1].cells[4].innerHTML = iPagePGV;
```

Or with...

```
var foot = $('tfoot').first();

foot.children().each(function(i, row) {

    row.cells[1].innerHTML = iPageCPSV;
    row.cells[2].innerHTML = iPageCGV;
    row.cells[3].innerHTML = iPagePPSV;
    row.cells[4].innerHTML = iPagePGV;
});
```

A more modern solution...

```
var rows = nRow.getElementsByTagName('tfoot')[0].rows,
    data = [iPageCPSV, iPageCGV, iPagePPSV, iPagePGV];

[].forEach.call(rows, function(el, i) {
    data.forEach(function(item, ii) {
        el.cells[ii + 1].innerHTML = item;
    });
});
```

---

Since you need different data for each cell, I'd suggest putting it all in an Array, getting a collection of all the elements, and pairing the two...

```
var data = [iPageCPSV, iPageCGV, iPagePPSV, iPagePGV, 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'buz'];

$('tfoot > tr > th:not(:first-child)').html(function(i, el) {
    return data[i];
});
```

Comment: That is what I was missing.  I was trying nCells [0][1].  I'm not too familier with javascript sadly.

Comment: I don't think `nRow` there is `table` element. May be it is the `tfoot->tr`.. I am not sure.. but this is the correct way to go.. +1

Comment: No loops fed from an array of the `iPage*` variables? You're breaking my heart ;)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Yeah, it's not very DRY. Iterating an Array would be much better.

Comment: @amnotiam oops.. I noticed it and deleted my comment >.<

Comment: Yeah the first cell [0] is pre filled with Total:  so I skip over that, I fill the other 4 cells with data gathered from the table.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Updated... just for you! `;)`

Comment: @amnotiam, duly noted, and +1 from me :)

Comment: I went with the jQuery option as I'm most familier with that.  Right now it works, but it is filling out both rows with the same data.  I need different data put in the second row.  I tried .row[0].cells[1] and that didn't work.  Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @JamesWilson: I'll update with another jQuery solution. Simplest will be to put all the data in an Array, and iterate that.

Comment: It worked, I had to remove the :nth-Child(1) for some reason it would not work with that, but it works perfectly now thank you!

Comment: @JamesWilson: Yes, it should have been `:eq(0)`, but was only needed if there was more than one `tfoot` in the document. Removing is best if it's the only one.